# How can I remove a portion of a string from the right side of a string starting at a special character

Tags: php, string, operators, truncate

I have a series of strings created as URLs as the page gets refreshed.I want to remove a portion from the right side of these strings. The strings look like:

```
http://funfun.ca/?image=1
http://funfun.ca/?image=14
http://funfun.ca/?image=217
```

and so on. The goal is for anything starting with "?" to be removed from the right side of the strings and leave the following for all of them:

```
http://funfun.ca/
```

I appreciate any help I can have to solve this

Comment: Is this your site or do you have it as a PHP variable in string format?

Comment: @DocZ did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may [`explode`](https://php.net/explode) the url string for `?` and save only the first part obtained:

```
$firstPart = explode('?', $url)[0];
```

Example:

```
echo $firstPart = explode('?', 'http://funfun.ca/?image=1')[0];
```

returns:

```
http://funfun.ca/
```

Comment: Thanks user2342558! you made my day. Thanks a million my friend